# What is the significance of APP_Browsers folder in project and significance of file called whateveryouwant.browser

Tags: ios, asp.net, iphone, .net-4.0

So here's my problem:

`LinkButton` was not working on Iphone - project runs using .net 4.0. 
`Linkbutton` was working fine on android and all other browser's except Iphone. So I found an article that said add the following in `whateveryouwant.browser` file in `APP_browsers` folder.

Which includes something like this:

```
<browsers> 
  <browser id="safariiphone" parentID="mozilla"> 
    <identification> 
      <userAgent match="AppleWebKit"/>    
    </identification> 
    <capabilities> 
        <capability name="version"                         value="${version}" /> 
        <capability name="majorversion"                    value="${major}" /> 
        <capability name="minorversion"                    value="${minor}" /> 
        <capability name="type"                            value="Safari${major}" /> 
        <capability name="ecmascriptversion"               value="3.0" /> 
        <capability name="javascript"                      value="true" /> 
        <capability name="javascriptversion"               value="1.6" /> 
        <capability name="w3cdomversion"                   value="1.0" /> 
        <capability name="tagwriter"                       value="System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter" /> 
        <capability name="cookies"                         value="true" /> 
        <capability name="frames"                          value="true" /> 
        <capability name="javaapplets"                     value="true" /> 
        <capability name="supportsAccesskeyAttribute"      value="true" /> 
        <capability name="supportsCallback"                value="true" /> 
        <capability name="supportsDivNoWrap"               value="false" /> 
        <capability name="supportsFileUpload"              value="true" /> 
        <capability name="supportsMaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" value="true" /> 
        <capability name="supportsMultilineTextBoxDisplay" value="true" /> 
        <capability name="supportsXmlHttp"                 value="true" /> 
        <capability name="tables"                          value="true" /> 
    </capabilities> 
  </browser> 
</browsers>
```

After I added this piece of code. Everything works as as expected and all `linkbutton` are working great on iphone.
What is the significance of all this code ? Why do we actually need this  and how it works ?

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, it tells the framework how to render the mark-up for the calling browser.

There are good articles about this:

http://www.shubho.net/2011/01/what-is-appbrowsers-folder-in-aspnet.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc57y7e.aspx (search for "**Configuring Browser Capabilities for Markup Validation**")

I recently had problems with javascript not working in IE11 and had to change *.browser file in app_browser. Not only that, you also need to delete the compile browser file from the bin (if it is a website) to make sure things get done.

Hope this helps.